# heat pump ecodan noise: constant or variable

Tags: heat-pump

I have just seen an Ecodan PUHZ-W85VAA in action at the house of the salesman. It running very quietly, but I wanted to know will it get louder as the weather gets colder? In other words does the pump have two running speeds (either on or off) or is it continuously variable?

Comment: I believe air source heat pumps tend to be noisiest when defrosting during cold weather.  I don't (yet!) have one myself though so that is hearsay.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have since spoken with somebody who owns an Ecodan and they confirm it's either on or off, with no intermediate levels in normal operation, though I didn't discover whether defrost cycles differ to this.